# UITableview with textfields to arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm not sure if I am approaching this the correct way so I need some help. I have a table with 5 rows for data to be entered. After the user enters all the data there is a button on the navigation bar that will add the data to the arrays. I want to set up another view controller that displays all of the data that has been entered by the user. I hope this makes sense. Here's what I have so far.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[self initWithStyle: UITableViewStyleGrouped];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
//self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
 //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: self action: @selector(add)] autorelease];

course = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
date = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
scores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
rating = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
slope = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {

        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
            playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            playerTextField.placeholder = @"Required";
            playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            playerTextField.text = [course objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            playerTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            [playerTextField setEnabled: YES];
            [cell addSubview:playerTextField];
            [playerTextField release];
        }
        else if([indexPath row] == 1){
            UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
            playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            playerTextField.placeholder = @"Required";
            playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
            playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            playerTextField.text = [date objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            playerTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            [playerTextField setEnabled: YES];
            [cell addSubview:playerTextField];
            [playerTextField release];
        }   
        else if([indexPath row] == 2){
            UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
            playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            playerTextField.placeholder = @"Required";
            playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
            playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            playerTextField.text = [scores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            playerTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            [playerTextField setEnabled: YES];
            [cell addSubview:playerTextField];
            [playerTextField release];
        }  
        else if([indexPath row] == 3){
            UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
            playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            playerTextField.placeholder = @"Required";
            playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
            playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
             playerTextField.text = [rating objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            playerTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            [playerTextField setEnabled: YES];
            [cell addSubview:playerTextField];
            [playerTextField release];
        }  
        else if([indexPath row] == 4){
            UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
            playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            playerTextField.placeholder = @"Required";
            playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
            playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            playerTextField.text = [slope objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            playerTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            [playerTextField setEnabled: YES];
            [cell addSubview:playerTextField];
            [playerTextField release];
        }  

    }
}
if ([indexPath section] == 0) { 
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) { 
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Course";
    }
    else if([indexPath row] == 1){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Date";
    }
    else if([indexPath row] == 2){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Score";
    }
    else if([indexPath row] == 3){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Rating";
    }
    else if([indexPath row] == 4){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Slope";
    }
}

return cell;    
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
[course replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
[date replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
[scores replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
[rating replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
[slope replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are having or is it working but you just want to be reassured that you are using the best-practice for this sort of design?

Comment: I just want to make sure this is the best way to go about designing the app. Im not sure how to set up the second view controller that with take the elements added to the arrays and display them in columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it just be easier to put 5 text fields in a view? I don't understand why you put them in a table view... If you want them to be scrollable, you can always just wrap your entire view in a scrollview, but I wouldn't do this with a table. As far as I know, it's generally bad to use a table view for input. It's more like a way to provide a user a display of some data, e.g. an array of objects. Also, usually, if you're using an `NSMutableArray` as a data source, you would also want your table data source methods like `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to return a value based on the size of the array, rather than a magic, hard coded number.

I also see you're doing a lot of work in the code. You can have Interface Builder do all this stuff for you: just make a new `UIViewController` subclass with a xib that goes by the same name, design it in Interface Builder, and write the logic in the .m file.

For example, let's say I have a subclass of `UIViewController` called `MyViewController`, which has a view with 1 button 'next' and 2 `UITextField`s, conveniently called `dateTF` and `scoreTF`. My .h file would look something like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *dateTF;
    IBOutlet UITextField *scoreTF;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *dateTF;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *scoreTF;

- (IBAction)clickedNext:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here we have a placeholder for the action that will be called when the "next" button is pressed, and 2 outlets to the text fields to retrieve the data from them. I don't need an IBOutlet to the button because I won't edit it.

The .m file could look like this:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize dateTF
@synthesize scoreTF;

// called when the button is clicked
- (IBAction)clickedNext:(id)sender{
    NSString * date = self.dateTF.text;
    NSString * score = self.scoreTF.text;
    // do something with this data, like put up a model and go to the next view
}

@end
```

This assumes I have a xib file that contains my UI. In the xib you'll also need to make a few connections (easily done with ctrl+click_and_drag from source to target, e.g. from button to File's Owner): you'll need to connect the 2 IBOutlets and the button to call the IBAction, and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the help but I never learned how to use interface builder. I was taught to do everything programmatically. I think I am going to just put 5 textfields like you said.

Answer (score 0):

I use data dictionary in passing data to a new viewController and uncomment the codes in the .m:

```
    /*
 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/
```

and add the new parameter in my case a dictionary:

Supposed the name is passDataHereController and selectedNews was declared as NSDictionary in the .h

```
// Note that I added the withDataDictionary:(NSDictionary*)passedDataDictionary
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withDataDictionary:(NSDictionary*)passedDataDictionary{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.selectedNews = passedDataDictionary;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then in the controller where you are going to pass the data

```
//supposed dataTobePassed is already populated
    passDataHereController *newView = [[passDataHereController alloc] initWithNibName:@"passDataHereController" bundle:nil withDataDictionary:dataTobePassed];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
    [newView release];
```

That's one way in passing data to another view, others may have simpler solutions.
Hope it helps.